# PHP,SQLSERVER y JS

Tags: php, javascript, html5, sql-server-2008

El código no funciona no me arroja ningún tipo de error no se que esta mal espero que puedan ayudarme.No funciona la validacion con js,tampoco me muestra los echo de la coneccion

```js
function valida(){
 var cod,nom,rut,fon,act,ema,dir;
  
  cod=document.getElementById("cod").value;
  nom=document.getElementById("nom").value;
  rut=document.getElementById("rut").value;
  fon=document.getElementById("fon").value;
  act=document.getElementById("act").value;
  ema=document.getElementById("email").value;
  dir=document.getElementById("dire").value;
 if(cod=""){
  alert("El campo Codigo auxiliar esta vacio");
 return false;

 }else if(nom=""){
  alert("El campo NOMBRE esta vacio");
   return false;
 }else if(rut=""){
  alert("Debe ingresar el rut");
   return false;
 }else if(fon=""){
  alert("Debe ingresar el número de telefono");
   return false;
 }else if(act=""){
  alert("El campo ACTIVIDAD esta vacio");
   return false;
 }else if(ema=""){
  alert("Debe ingresar un email");
   return false;
 }else if(dir=""){
  alert("Debe ingresar una direccion");
   return false;
 }
 formato_email=/\w+@+\w+\.+[a-z]/;
}
```

```css
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
require 'conexion.php';
cone();
if($_POST['btn_ingresar']){
$cod = $_POST['cod'];
$nombre = $_POST['nom']; 
$rut = $_POST['rut']; 
$act = $_POST['act'];
$fono = $_POST['fon']; 
$correo=$_POST['email'];
$direcion=$_POST['dire']; 
$comprobar= sqlsrv_qery($con,"SELECT CodAux FROM softland.CWTAUXI WHERE CodAux=$cod");
if($comprobar==true){
 echo"El cliente ya esta registrado ";
  echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}else{
$insertarc=sqlsrv_qery($con,"Insert Into xx ( CodAux,NomAux,NoFAux, RutAux,ActAux,GirAux, PaiAux,Region, CiuAux,Comaux,Provaux, DirAux,DirNum,DirDpto, CodPostal,FonAux1,FonAux2, FonAux3,CodAreaFon, AnexoFon,FaxAux1,FaxAux2, CodAreaFax,
     ClaCli, ClaPro, ClaEmp, ClaSoc,ClaDis,ClaOtr,  Casilla,Email, WebSite, Bloqueado, BloqueadoPro, Notas , EsReceptorDTE ,EMailDTE, CtaCliente, CtaCliMonExt) VALUES ( '$cod',  '$nom', Null, '$rut', 'S', Null, Null,  Null , Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, '$fono', ' ', ' ', 0, 0 , ' ', ' ', 0, 'S', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', Null, '$correo', Null, 'N', 'N', Null , 'N',  Null , NULL, NULL)");

if(!$ejecutar){
    printf("Error en ejecución: %s\n", $con->error);
 echo "0<br>";
echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}else{
    echo "El vendedor de registro exitosamente en la BD ";
 echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}
}
}

 ?>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registrar clientes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/validar.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="procesos.php" method="post" onSubmit="return valida();">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="imagenes/logo.png" width="90%" height="10%">
    </div>
    <h2>Ingresar clientes</h2>
  <div class="input_style">
  <input type="text" name="cod" placeholder="Codigo auxiliar">
  <input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nombre">
  <input type="text" name="rut" placeholder="Rut">
  <input type="text" name="act" placeholder="Activo">
  <input type="text" name="fon" placeholder="Telofono">
  <input type="text" name="em" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="text" name="dire" placeholder="Direccion">
  <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="btn_ingresar" class="btn">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if(cod=""){ //Aqui son == o ===. Te recomiendo que uses === y para desigualdad: !== esto te garantiza que sea exactamente el mismo tipo de variable.

Comment: Hola Johann Sebastian. Por favor lee [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus publicaciones. Por ejemplo, los títulos deben ser descriptivos, el cuerpo de la pregunta debe indicar cuál es el problema (¿cómo no funciona?¿qué error recibes?), qué es lo que hace el código, cuál es el comportamiento esperado y cuál es el comportamiento que recibes. Las preguntas sin un enunciado claro normalmente se consideran de baja calidad y no son útiles para otros usuarios.

Comment: Esta bien, gracias por ponerme al tanto soy nuevo en esta plaaforma

Answer (score 0):

Por lo pronto veo varios detalles, en el HTML no has definido ningun ID para los campos del form.

```
 <input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nombre">
```

no hay id por lo que esto:

```
nom=document.getElementById("nom").value;
```

nunca te puede devolver nada debes dejarlo:

`<input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Nombre">`
luego en la misma función en tu js tiene otro error aunque esto ya te lo han puesto más arriba yo te lo voy a remarcar

`if(cod=""){`

estas igualando, no comparando. Por lo que tendrías que dejarlo así:

`if(cod === ""){`

aunque tambien puede servirte

`if(cod.lenght === 0){`

En JavaScript suele ser aconsejable usar el comparador estricto, pero tambien vale el comparador ==